# How to properly set $.cookie so it will only be alive on current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Im using $.cookie to save my current's page form even after a reload:

here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
if($.cookie('Table_Rows')){
loadCookieData();
$(".qty, .price").bind("keyup change", calculate);
 }
 else{addRow(0);}
});
```

Im saving my cookies before the page reload: (is it okay for me to this?)

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(event)
{
storeRowData();
console.log("cookie saved!");
};
```

But my main problem is even if I navigate to other pages like:

`http://mydomain.dev/purchase_orders/create/2` <--cookie created here

`http://mydomain.dev/purchase_orders/create/3` <-- `loadCookieData();` will still be triggered?

I want it to stay on 1 url/page only and will not affect other pages? any Idea please?

storeRowData.js

```
var storeRowData = function () {
 var data = []; 
$('#tblItemList tbody>tr:visible').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),

        pId = $this.find("#itemId").val();
        pname = $this.find('input.itemSearch').attr("value"),
        desc = $this.find(".description").val(),
        quant = $this.find(".qty").val(),
        rowId = $this.find(".rowId").val(),
        price = $this.find(".price").val();

    var temp = { 
        productName: pname, 
        itemId:pId,
        description: desc,
        quantity: quant, 
        price: price, 
        rowId: rowId };
    data.push(temp);
});
$.cookie('Table_Rows', JSON.stringify(data), {expires: 7, path: '/'});
}
```

loadCookieData.js

```
function loadCookieData(){

temp = $.cookie('Table_Rows');
var parseData = JSON.parse(temp);
console.log(parseData);
var html ='';



for (i in parseData) {

    subTotal = parseData[i].quantity*parseData[i].price;
    var st = new Number(subTotal);
    var sub = st.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, '$1,');

html+="<tr><td><input id='itemName"+parseData[i].rowId+"' value='"+parseData[i].productName+"' required name='product["+parseData[i].rowId+"][name]' class='form-control col-lg-5 itemSearch' type='text' placeholder='select item' />"+
  "<input type='hidden' class='rowId' value='"+parseData[i].rowId+"'>"+
  "<input type='hidden' name='product[" + parseData[i].rowId + "][itemId]' value='"+parseData[i].itemId+"' id='itemId'></td>"+
  "<td><textarea readonly name='product["+parseData[i].rowId+"][description]' class='form-control description' rows='1' >"+parseData[i].description+"</textarea></td>"+
  "<td><input type='number' value='"+parseData[i].quantity+"' min='1' max='9999' name='product["+parseData[i].rowId+"][quantity]' class='qty form-control' required />"+
  "<input id='poItemId' type='hidden' name='product[" + parseData[i].rowId + "][poContentId]'></td>"+
  "<td><input type='number' value='"+parseData[i].price+"' min='1' step='any' max='9999' name='product["+parseData[i].rowId+"][price]' class='price form-control' required /></td>"+
  "<td class='subtotal'><center><h3>"+sub+"</h3></center></td>"+
  "<input type='hidden' name='product["+parseData[i].rowId+"][delete]' class='hidden-deleted-id'>"+
  "<td class='actions'><a href='#' class='btnRemoveRow btn btn-danger'>x</a></td>"+
  "</tr>";
    }

$("#tblItemList tbody").html(html);

for (i in parseData){
  var inputBox = "#itemName"+parseData[i].rowId;
  $(inputBox).select2(sOptions);
}
calculate(); 
}
```

Any suggestions/Comments would really be appreciated! Thank you very much for your time and have a good day ahead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the page information whenever you save the cookie.

If you are on page http://mydomain.dev/purchase_orders/create/2 , try saving the cookie as

```
$.cookie('Table_Rows-2', JSON.stringify(data), {expires: 7, path: '/'});
```

Whenever you try and load a cookie, use the page number and the Table_Rows-2 cookie won't load if you're on page 3.

Comment: would that be okay?? I mean what if I have a thousand pages? mmm then I should be deleting the previous cookie I made right? anyways Thank you so much for your answer. gave me some ways to do it :)

Comment: I'm not sure if you want the cookies to be stored in case people go back to previous pages, but if you have thousands of pages you should delete the cookies or make sure they expire after a certain time period.  You should also check out the jquery .unload() method, which you can use to delete cookies before a user leaves the page.

Comment: I see, I think that would be the best thing I can do right now. Thank you very much for sharing your thoughts.